# Render via map instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, rendering

I am currently using this function to render some elements & display results after a graphql query:

```
 const showUsers = React.useCallback(
    (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult, numberOfUsers: Number) => {
      if (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
          const userName = data.users.nodes[i].firstName
            .concat(' ')
            .concat(data.users.nodes[i].lastName);
          return (
            <View style={styles.friends}>
              <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
                <View style={styles.addButtonContainer}>
                  <Button
                    rounded
                    onPress={() => {
                      addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[i].id));
                      setIsSubmitted(false);
                      setUserData(null);
                    }}>
                    <Icon name="plus" size={moderateScale(20)} color="black" />
                  </Button>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }
      }
    },
    [createUserRelationMutation, userData, numberOfUsers],
  );
```

I have read that using a for loop isn't a good idea. Hence, I am trying to switch to a map but I am unable to. I couldn't figure out how to use variables like `const userName`while using a map.

Currently, I can only test with `numberOfUsers = 1`so it works fine but in reality, I want all of the `item` contained in the `View`which is styled as `friends`. For now, there will be a separate `<View style={styles.friends}>`for each item. However, I want to map all items inside one single `<View style={styles.friends}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything to be contained inside the view styled as friends this is how the code should be.

You should have the map inside the view as JS code and access properties from the item variable.

```
const showUsers = React.useCallback(
  (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult, numberOfUsers: Number) => {
    if (data) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.friends}>
          {
            data.users.nodes.map(item => {
              const userName = item.firstName
                .concat(' ')
                .concat(item.lastName);

                return (<View style={styles.item}>
                  <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
                  <View style={styles.addButtonContainer}>
                    <Button
                      rounded
                      onPress={() => {
                        addFriend(Number(item.id));
                        setIsSubmitted(false);
                        setUserData(null);
                      }}>
                      <Icon name="plus" size={moderateScale(20)} color="black" />
                    </Button>
                  </View>
                </View>);
            })

          }
        </View>
      );
    }
  },
  [createUserRelationMutation, userData, numberOfUsers],
);
```

Comment: and numberOfUsers isn't doing anything anymore right?

Comment: No you dont need it anymore as you are not using the loop

Comment: Just realised that using a map instead of the for loop gives me the ```each child in a list should have a unique key prop```warning. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I believe I'll have to add some sort of key but I am not sure about where to put it syntactically. Adding ```key={item.id}```to the first View in the second return gave overloading errors

Comment: You have to add the key to the inner view like this <View style={styles.item} key={item.id}>

Answer (score 1):

Map takes a function as its argument, which means that you can use that same code from the for loop inside of the function passed to the map, like this:

```js
data.users.map((user) => {
          const userName = user.firstName
            .concat(' ')
            .concat(user.lastName);
          return (
            <View style={styles.friends}>
              <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
                <View style={styles.addButtonContainer}>
                  <Button
                    rounded
                    onPress={() => {
                      addFriend(Number(user.id));
                      setIsSubmitted(false);
                      setUserData(null);
                    }}>
                    <Icon name="plus" size={moderateScale(20)} color="black" />
                  </Button>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }
```

Just replace all instances of `data.users.nodes[i]` with `user` since that's what each object in the array is passed into the function as.

For more info about this, check [this part of the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).